# Where to find the documentation of ENPC (UDP port 3289, printer discovery)?

Tags: sockets

I want my software to communicate with thermal printers and wonder how to do a network search for them. I have found out so far that it can be done via the "ENPC", which uses UDP port 3289. But where to find the details?

Here is the only hint I found so far:
[https://epson.com/faq/SPT_C11CG18201~faq-0000525-shared?faq_cat=faq-8796127635532](https://epson.com/faq/SPT_C11CG18201%7Efaq-0000525-shared?faq_cat=faq-8796127635532)

Comment: I found a bit more: https://github.com/BlackLotus/epson-stuff

Comment: Someone is looking for it here, too: https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php/issues/923, and some of the Epson SDKs seem to have discovery options which might use ENPC (https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_epos_sdk_and_en/index.php?content_id=103)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know more about ENPC as well.  This is the only thing I found:

http://support.epostraders.co.uk/support-files/documents/31/nzw-UB-E02_TechnicalReferenceGuide.pdf

Starting on page 4-11, there is some sample code that at least confirms what the query packet is, but no info on what to expect in a response.  I'm pasting the code here in case the above link goes dead.

```c
/* UDP3289 programming sample for win32
 * HOW TO BUILD
 * cc wudp.cpp wsock32.lib
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock.h>

#define MAXBUF 512
char buf[MAXBUF];

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    WSADATA data;
    SOCKET sock;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int i, len, fromlen;

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("usage: wudp <IP address>\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* initialize windows socket */
    WSAStartup(0x0101, &data);

    /* Create socket */
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error socket(): %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }

    /* initialize the parameter */
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(3289);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);

    /* make a packet (PRINTER STATUS) */
    buf[0] = 'E';
    buf[1] = 'P';
    buf[2] = 'S';
    buf[3] = 'O';
    buf[4] = 'N';
    buf[5] = 'Q'; // PacketType(Q)
    buf[6] = 0x03; // DeviceType(3)
    buf[7] = 0x00; // DeviceNumber(0)
    buf[8] = 0x00; // Function(0010h)
    buf[9] = 0x10;
    
    buf[10] = 0x00; // Result
    buf[11] = 0x00;
    buf[12] = 0x00; // Parameter length
    buf[13] = 0x00;

    /* send a packet */
    i = sendto(sock, buf, 14, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));

    /* receive packet */
    fromlen = sizeof(addr);
    len = recvfrom(sock, buf, MAXBUF, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &fromlen);

    /* print receive packet */
    if (len) {
        if ((buf[10] == 0x00) && (buf[11] == 0x00))
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
                printf("%3d:%02Xh\n", i, buf[i] & 0xff);
    }

    /* close socket */
    closesocket(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Additional info (October 31, 2023)

The first 13 bytes of response are always an echo of what was broadcasted (minus one byte).

Broadcast: `"EPSONQ" 03 00 00 10 00 00 00 00`

Response: 27 bytes total, I don't see anything useful.

Broadcast: `"EPSONQ" 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`

Response: 147 bytes total

- bytes 20+: Epson Model followed by null bytes (00)

Broadcast: `"EPSONQ" 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00`

Response: 37 bytes total

- bytes 16-21: MAC Address
- bytes 24-27: IP Address
- bytes 28-31: Subnet Mask
- bytes 32-35: Gateway